# Chrome, when using width="100%", images become blurred?

Tags: google-chrome, tags, width, image

I'm using Google Chrome, and have a 1440px wide display. I made the images about that wide,  and whenever I use the attribute width="100%" with the img tag, it blurs the image.

When I add it however, it downsizes the image to the exact screen size.

Not sure if this is a Chrome issue, or there is another way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the dimension of your image ?

Comment: The size of the image that I'm currently working with is 1440x94.

Comment: Although, I'm looking to do this with multiple images.

Comment: right click & "Inspect Element", note the dimension of the image. See if it is downsized or upscaled.

Comment: that's why it blurs. you'd better set it to its actual pixel / leave it unset.

Comment: Try this link, seems to work well. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109554

Answer (score 1):

You may have misunderstood the meaning of 100%. The value of width is not to the image itself but to the parent's width. So you may need to specify the width to be `width="1440"` or with a css style `width:1440px` or leave it unset to keep the original size (not recommended as it may sometimes cause bad layout during the loading time)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue, only on chrome. 
I use a workaround with a div with background-image, the blur disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
image-rendering: crisp-edges;
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;  /* IE (non-standard property) */
```

| https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering